# Simplifying php code

Tags: php, function

I'm working on revamping my CMS right now. Currently, I'm trying to minimize the front end code to make theming easier. To display the latest posts, this is the code I am using:

```
<?php 
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts order by id desc") or die(mysql_error());
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) :
?>
   <h3><a href="?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></a></h3>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

What would be the best way to simplify this for the front end user? I'm thinking about using a functions.php file but I not sure exactly how to do that. Is there a way I could make the first two lines of php into a function and then the user would only have to call the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the function you could use:

```
function getPosts() {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts order by id desc") or die(mysql_error());
    $result = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

and in the template:

```
<?php foreach(getPosts() as $post) : ?>
<h3><a href="?id=<?php echo $post->id ?>"><?php echo $row->title ?></a></h3>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I'm not having any luck with that code...I suspect it's because of something I did though...hmm

Comment: I copied your code exactly and now all I get is a blank page. Nothing is shown.

Comment: in your foreach loop, you should have `getPosts()` not `$getPosts()`

Answer (score 2):

Typically you use two layers.

- Database access layer: Query function accepts arbitrary queries, verifies return value, logs to file on error, dies if needed. You can create separate functions for querying+retrieving data in one step (query_one_row(), query_dataset_as_array(), ...).
- Data model layer: Separate functions for each major query, each calling the lower layer. eg: get_recent_posts(),

Try to rewrite @Sascha's answer to use these two layers.

Answer (score 1):

note: i know I'm not answering your question, but just wanted to give you a heads up.

you might want to split the different concerns of the code. on one hand there is the render of the data, on the other hand, the business logic and the persistance layer. it seems you're coding everything in one file and this may make matters complex in the future. try using an mvc like yii, zend framework, or symfony2.

also, the "or die" is pretty much a bad practice. notice how you are loosing the chance of logging the error properly and outputing the error directly to the user instead of giving them a nice error page to look at, and maybe give you some feedback about the error.

edit: for the persistance layer, you could try doctrine2

Answer (score 0):

To improve a little on Sascha's answer above, you could do this...

```
<?php

foreach(getPosts() as $post)
{
    printf( '<h3><a href="?id=%d">%s</a></h3>', $post->id, $row->title );
}

?>
```

Works exactly the same, but a bit easier to read, imo.

Comment: not having any luck with that. Maybe I'm missing something here?

Comment: well, obviously, you still need Sascha's getPosts() function, for it to work. What other issues are you having?