# How to simplify this php code

Tags: php

I need some help and explaning how to simplify my php code.

It's working but it seems to be little to much of repeating code.

Basically I want to check the day and time for showing preformatted text when the shop is closed and different text on desktop or mobile devices.

Thanks for reading.

```
    <?php
    include 'Mobile_Detect.php';
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect();
    //Get time
    $hour = date("H", mktime(date("H")));
    $day = date("D");

    if($day == 'Mon'  && ($hour >= 6 && $hour < 22)) {
        if ($detect->isMobile()) 
        {
        include 'online_mobile.php';
        } else 
        {
        include 'online_desktop.php'; 
        }
    }       
    elseif($day == 'Tue'  && ($hour >= 6 && $hour < 22)) {
        if ($detect->isMobile()) 
        {
        include 'online_mobile.php';
        } else 
        {
        include 'online_desktop.php'; 
        }
    }                           
    elseif($day == 'Wed'  && ($hour >= 6 && $hour < 22)) {
        if ($detect->isMobile()) 
        {
        include 'online_mobile.php';
        } else 
        {
        include 'online_desktop.php'; 
        }
    }                   
    elseif($day == 'Thu'  && ($hour >= 6 && $hour < 22)) {
        if ($detect->isMobile()) 
        {
        include 'online_mobile.php';
        } else 
        {
        include 'online_desktop.php'; 
        }
    }                       
    elseif($day == 'Fri'  && ($hour >= 6 && $hour < 22)) {
        if ($detect->isMobile()) 
        {
        include 'online_mobile.php';
        } else 
        {
        include 'online_desktop.php'; 
        }
    }               
    elseif($day == 'Sat'  && ($hour >= 8 && $hour < 18)) {
        if ($detect->isMobile()) 
        {
        include 'online_mobile.php';
        } else 
        {
        include 'online_desktop.php'; 
        }
    }                       
    elseif($day == 'Sun'  && ($hour >= 8 && $hour < 18)) {
        if ($detect->isMobile()) 
        {
        include 'online_mobile.php';
        } else 
        {
        include 'online_desktop.php'; 
        }
} else {
    if ($detect->isMobile()) 
    {
    include 'closed_mobile.php';
    } else 
    {
    include 'closed_desktop.php'; 
    } 
}
?>
```

Regards R.C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplifying php code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779163/simplifying-php-code)

Comment: If this is working code I'd say it should be discussed at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not here at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
$include = '';

    if( in_array($day, array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri') ) && ($hour >= 6 && $hour < 22) ) {

        $include = $detect->isMobile() ? 'online_mobile' : 'online_desktop';
    }

    if($day == 'Sat'  && ($hour >= 8 && $hour < 18)) {
        $include = $detect->isMobile() ? 'online_mobile' : 'online_desktop'; 
    }

    if($day == 'Sun'  && ($hour >= 8 && $hour < 18)) {
        $include = $detect->isMobile() ? 'online_mobile' : 'online_desktop';
} else {
    $include = $detect->isMobile() ? 'closed_mobile' : 'closed_desktop'; 
}        

include $include.'php';
```

Comment: This is really nice ! I go learning aray's :-) Thanks a lot ! Much smaller and cleaner.

Comment: You should check it as answered so other people know it aswell

Comment: I was thinking : Is it possible to read the days and times from a text or csv file and use this in the example above ? Text file like : "Mon","7","18"
"Tue","7","18"
"Wed","7","18"
"Thu","7","18"
"Fri","7","18"
"Sat","0","0"
"Sun","0","0" Sat and Sun is closed ;-)

Comment: In that case you might aswell put it in a database. But yes it should be possible